# Peculiar issue adding series to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a peculiar issue. I have 2 dataframes, x with 180k rows, y with 700 rows. I am creating another series z by looking up a column from x into y and getting a third column as series. But when I add this series to x, the values change completely. Given below are the two count distributions. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
z=pd.merge(x,y,how='left',left_on='xcol1',right_on='ycol1')['ycol2']
x['colnew']=z
z.value_counts()
x['colnew'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Is 'z' not a DataFrame when you do pd.merge()? It should be.

Comment: What do you mean by "looking up a column from x into y?"

Answer (score 0):

Check the len of z series. May be you have repeated keys in y or not have corresponding keys, so z may have not same size as x['colnew'].

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this pandas documentation for merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), specifically the Jupyter notebook like `[44].`

I think an issue could be that the "keys" do not line up. The argument `left_on='xcol1'` specifies `xcol1` as the join key for dataframe `x`, and similarly `right_on='ycol1'` specifies `ycol1` as the join key for dataframe `y.`

1. The `how` argument determines which keys to keep in your merged dataframe. Here since you specified `how='left'` which corresponds to dataframe `x`, if dataframe `y` has keys that are not included in dataframe `x`'s keys, they will be discarded. **Consequence: you could end up with a merged dataframe `z` which is smaller (in terms of number of rows i.e. observations) than what you expect.**
2. If the join keys from dataframe `x` and dataframe `y` do not match up, the corresponding variable values will be mapped to `NaN`. **Consequence: `value_counts()` will change because there will be more `NaN` values, which do not get counted in this function.**

Answer (score 0):

Figured that out. I basically had to use

```
x['colnew']=z.values
```

It's very surprising, have never encountered this before.